# Advanced search with "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived" using OR and AND

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to do an advanced search in Outlook. I use python and win32com to do it.

My query ignores my date filter.

```
"urn:schemas:mailheader:subject" like '%draft%' OR 
"urn:schemas:mailheader:subject" ci_phrasematch 'draft' OR 
"urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" like '%draft%' OR 
"urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" ci_phrasematch 'draft' AND 
"urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"  > '01.06.2017 12:00 AM'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your query may be working exactly as instructed

i think that you may need to add brackets into your logic statement

your query checks the date only when

```
("urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" ci_phrasematch 'draft') = TRUE
```

you most likely want this :

```
    (   ("urn:schemas:mailheader:subject"       like           '%draft%')
     OR ("urn:schemas:mailheader:subject"       ci_phrasematch 'draft'  )
     OR ("urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" like           '%draft%')
     OR ("urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription" ci_phrasematch 'draft'  )
    )
AND ("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"  > '01.06.2017 12:00 AM')
```

Comment: When creating new folder is this filter applied automatically?    %lastweek("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived").  I am facing a trouble to remove filter each time I create a new folder.